# How to disable scrolling back to top on a SingleChildScrollView when calling setState in flutter

Tags: forms, scroll, flutter

I have a SingleChildScrollView widget whose child is a Form widget in Flutter. Whenever I made some changes to the radio buttons or switches inside the form and calling setState() method, the view scrolls to the top.
How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend passing through a custom ScrollController when constructing your SingleChildScrollView widget.

ScrollController has a property called 'keepScrollOffset' which you need to set to true.

From the documentation at https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html

keepScrollOffset → bool
Each time a scroll completes, save the current scroll offset with PageStorage and restore it if this controller's scrollable is recreated. [...]
final

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after update Flutter SDK version from 2.8.0 to 3.1.0. For me the solution was set a GlobalKey to AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics.

```
final GlobalKey scrollKey = GlobalKey();
SingleChildScrollView(physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),key: scrollKey, ...
```