# How to prevent Flutter app from scrolling to top after calling setState?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an `ExpansionPanelList` inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. Whenever I (un)fold a panel and therefore call `setState`, the `SingleChildScrollView` scrolls back to the top. How can I prevent this?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  return new Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: new SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new ExpansionPanelList(
        children: <ExpansionPanel>[
          // panels
        ],
        expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
          setState(() {
            // toggle expanded
          });
        },
      ), // ExpansionPanelList
    ), // SingleChildScrollView
  ); // Scaffold
}
```

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427137/4934409) suggests using a custom `ScrollController` with `keepScrollOffset` set to `true`, however this is the default value and setting it explicitly to `true` therefore does not change anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because you are using a new `Key` every time you rebuild the widget (setState).

To fix your issue just move the code below outside the `build` method

```
 final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Like this :

```
 final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you! This also solved another problem that I didn't even realize I had, which is, the `ExpansionPanelList` wasn't animated at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a key to the `SingleChildScrollView`. Otherwise, its state is renewed every `setState` call.

```
 final _scrollKey = GlobalKey();

   SingleChildScrollView(
        key: _scrollKey,
        child:
```

Comment: This worked in my case. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was having the **same problem**, and somehow **the answer from @diegoveloper did not do the trick for me**.

What i ended up doing was separating the `SingleChildScrollView` in an independent `StatefulWidget`: That also fixed the scroll animation.

My code then ended up being something like

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: MyExpansionList(),
...

class MyExpansionListextends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyExpansionListState createState() => _MyExpansionListState();
}

class _MyExpansionListState extends State<MyExpansionList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      showTrackOnHover: true,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ExpansionPanelList(animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
```

In this way the `setState()` did update only the `ExpansionPanelList`/`ScrollView` and not the whole `Scaffold`.

I hope this also helps others facing same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helped me until I realised that in the `build()` function I was calling `jumpTo()` of the controller that was attached to my list. Like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (widget.controller.hasClients) {
    widget.controller.jumpTo(0);
  }
  ...
}
```

I removed these lines and the problem was gone. Happy coding :)